# Asp.Net Route Breaks When Changing .ASPX Filename

Tags: asp.net, routes

If I execute the application with this route defined:

RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("PermalinkRoute", "product/{permalink}", "~/Product.aspx");

And then change the filename of the Product.aspx to say, ProductHandler.aspx, the route ceases to function.

Trying to create or modify any route from this point forward does not work.

Any suggestions?